# DateTime Time Zone conversion bug

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, datetime-conversion

I try to convert my local time (Kiyv, Riga, UTC+02:00) to UTC, but there is an error in the following method

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(clientDate,
    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(tTimeZone.SystemId));
```

- `clientDate` is `19.06.2015 16:35:00`
- `tTimeZone.SystemId` is `FLE Standard Time`

The result is `19.06.2015 13:35:00`, but as I know the result should be  `19.06.2015 14:35:00`

Why does this method return a result that has a 3 hours difference?

Comment: Europe and Ukraine have same DST rules as i understand https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time

Comment: Assuming your `DateTime` is in local time why not just call `ToUniversalTime()`?

Comment: That code works on my local machine, but it will work on another server, so i need to convert client date to UTC date using time zone information.

Comment: Just google "Local time in Riga" and you'll instantly see that this is not a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this link](http://www.timebie.com/timelocal/fle.php);

> !!! Note: Currently [FLE Summer Time](http://www.timebie.com/timelocal/flesummer.php) is
>   observed.

And this says it is UTC+3 currently. That's why it's too normal to get 3 hour differences when you calculate them.

As Hans Passanst says, when you write Google as `Local time in Kyiv` or `Local time in Riga`, both search result says  (GMT+3)

Looks like DST started in 29 Mar 2015 and will end in 25 Oct 2015.

Comment: Thanks, but why DateTime.UtcNow property returns me the difference in two hours (19.06.2015 14:35:00) ?

Comment: What time zone that your current machine using? Have you ever check it on your machine settings?

Comment: My location is Ukraine (Kiev timezone) to GMT+3 , but DateTime.UtcNow returns me my local time subtract 2 hours